# What controllers work with aframe.io?

Tags: controller, aframe, virtual-reality

I've been blown away by [aframe](http://aframe.io), and I want to start walking around the scenes I design.

I've paired the cheap bluetooth controller that came with my headset (blitzwolf VR), but that doesn't work with aframe (or google cardboard). A bluetooth keyboard doesn't work either.

What should I be using to test movement on mobile VR? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess here and say that it's possible that you haven't enabled the Gamepad API for your browser, so although your phone is connecting to and responding to your gamepad, your browser can't.  I'm reasonably sure that the latest version of Chrome on mobile, (and Chrome in general), has the Gamepad API disabled by default, so you'll have to chase after it.

Go to chrome://flags in your browser then look for the entry that says "Gamepad Extensions" and flip the entry from "Default" to "Enabled".  From there, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

A-Frame, as of v0.7.0, has built-in support for the following tracked controllers:

- vive-controls
- oculus-touch-controls
- daydream-controls
- gearvr-controls
- windows-motion-controls

There is also a handy [`laser-controls` component](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/laser-controls.html) that auto-detects any of the above and adds basic interactivity or the [`progressive-controls` component](https://github.com/wmurphyrd/aframe-super-hands-component#progressive-controls-component) from the `super-hands` library for more complex interactivity that adjusts based on the controller's capabilities.

You can add support for other tracked controllers by extending the [`tracked-controls` component](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/tracked-controls.html).

For other types of controls like a gamepad or keyboard, you can use standard Web APIs to interface just like on a non-vr website, or you could use the [`universal-controls` component](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/controls) from the `aframe-extras` library.